# How to deploy multi - tier application with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

If I have a multi - tier application (say web / logic / database), where each tier having it's own container, and I need to deploy all of these en - bloc, do they all have to go into the same pod?

And if they are in the same pod, does this have any implications in terms of the maximum size of application that can be run?

Or is there some higher level abstraction that I can use to start all three layers, but have them running on different minions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to deploy all of the components together? In a micro services architecture, you would want to reduce the dependencies between each layer to a clean interface and then allow each layer to be deployed and scaled separately from the others.

If you need to deploy them together (e.g. they share local disk or localhost networking) then you need to deploy them as a single pod. A single pod is an atomic scheduling unit, so it will be deployed onto a single host machine. Since it lands on a single host, this limits the scalability of your application to the size of a single host (not allowing you to scale out as your traffic increases).

If your three layers are not tightly coupled, then you can run them in different pods, which allows them to be scheduled across multiple hosts (or on the same host if, for example, you are doing local development). To connect the pods together, you can define [services](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/services.md).

You should take a look at the [guestbook example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/guestbook) which illustrates how to define pods and services for a simple multi-tier web application running on Kubernetes.

Comment: I'm thinking of an old school application here, that I want to containerise.

So "deploying the app" means deploying all of the components.  They could run on separate machines, but from the users perspective the app isn't deployed until all of them are up and running.

So what I want to do is to create a "logical deployment unit" that is all of the required components for the app and deploy it in a single operation.

I would prefer not to be limited to a single host for the reasons of scalability that you outlined above.

Comment: If you put all of the yaml files into a single directory, you can create all of your application resources with a single command (`kubectl create -f <dir>`). We don't do this in the tutorials because it's better to start by seeing what each yaml file does in isolation, but this is how we run the end-to-end test for the guestbook application (see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/test/e2e/kubectl.go#L134).

Comment: the guy did not mention anything about microservices. strange accepted answer ;)